# How to auto count the number of rows and cols for the tables with or without row names

Tags: r

I try to write multiple tables into an excel file. Is it a way that I can get count of each table and then define the row where I can insert the next one?

Sample tables are:

```
tbl1 <- structure(list(`Event Count A` = c(NA, 
"72", "71 (98.61%)", "1 (1.39%)", "NA (NA%)"), `Event Count B` = c("22", 
"22", "0 (0.00%)", "0 (0.00%)", "12 (16.67%)"), `Patient Count A` = c(13L, 
13L, 1L, 12L, 8L), `Patient Count B` = c(8L, 
0L, 0L, NA, 72L)), row.names = c("Total number of patients", 
"Total number of AEs", "Non-Serious AE", 
"Serious AE", "Missing SAE Indicator"), class = "data.frame")

tbl2 <-structure(list(`Age Group` = c("Foetus (0 yr)", "Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)", 
"Infant (0.083-1.999 yrs.)", "Child (2-12.999 yrs.)", "Adolescent (13-17.999 yrs.)", 
"Adult (18-64.999 yrs.)", "Elderly (65-199 yrs.)", "Total"), 
    `Patient Count A` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 3L, 10L, 13L), `Patient Count B` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

tbl3 <- structure(list(`Event Count A` = c(NA, 
"72", "71 (98.61%)", "1 (1.39%)", "NA (NA%)"), `Event Count B` = c("22", 
"22", "0 (0.00%)", "0 (0.00%)", "12 (16.67%)"), `Patient Count A` = c(13L, 
13L, 1L, 12L, 8L), `Patient Count B` = c(8L, 
0L, 0L, NA, 72L)), row.names = c("Total number of patients", 
"Total number of AEs", "Non-Serious AE", 
"Serious AE", "Missing SAE Indicator"), class = "data.frame")

tbl4 <-structure(list(`Age Group` = c("Foetus (0 yr)", "Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)", 
"Infant (0.083-1.999 yrs.)", "Child (2-12.999 yrs.)", "Adolescent (13-17.999 yrs.)", 
"Adult (18-64.999 yrs.)", "Elderly (65-199 yrs.)", "Total"), 
    `Patient Count A` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 3L, 10L, 13L), `Patient Count B` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

The part of the codes to write them into Excel are:

```
###### Create a new excel workbook #################
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "Sample")

# Table 1: 
writeData(wb,sheet = "Sample", x = "Table 1",startRow = 1)
writeData(wb,sheet = "Sample", x = tbl1, colNames = TRUE,rowNames = TRUE,startRow = 2,  borders = "all")
addStyle(wb,sheet = "Sample", style = tableheaderStyle, rows = 2, cols = 1:Y (Y=5 for table 1), stack = TRUE)

# Table 2:
writeData(wb,sheet = "Sample", x = "Table 2",startRow = X)
writeData(wb,sheet = "Sample", x = tbl2,colNames = TRUE,startRow = X+1?, borders = "all")
addStyle(wb,sheet = "Sample", style = tableheaderStyle, rows = 2, cols = 1:Y (Y=3 for table 2, stack = TRUE)
```

I would like to know whether it is possible to auto change x and y based on the row and col for each insert table? Leave an empty row between each table. One challenge is some of the tables have row names and some don't. Manually count them are too slow and easy to make mistake.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This gets close to an answer:

```
library(openxlsx)

tbls <- list(tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4)         
rows <- cumsum(sapply(tbls, nrow))
cols <- sapply(tbls, ncol)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "Sample")

writeData(wb,sheet = "Sample", x = "All tables",startRow = 1)
          
for(i in 1:length(rows)) {
  writeData(wb, sheet = "Sample", tbls[[i]], colNames = TRUE, startRow = rows[i], borders = "all")
  addStyle(wb,sheet = "Sample", style = headerStyle, rows = rows[i], cols = 1:cols[i], stack = TRUE)
}
         
saveWorkbook(wb, "writeDate.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

For the, "One challenge is some of the tables have row names and some don't.", what differentiates them = The present of an "Age Group".

Comment: There is no rule to differentiates the tables with or without row names. It is depend on each tables design. The sample tables are just for test

Comment: I think `startRow` should not be `rows[i]`.  Do you think if I rename each table can help with adding table title?

Comment: `rows[i]` is needed so each table starts after the tables above it.  `rows` is the sums of each rows in each table.

Comment: I think we can use `.row_names_info( )` to test whether a table has row name or not. if it is positive, then with row names, negative, without row names.

Comment: I can't quite picture it without seeing the data, but you're onto something.  Often it's easier to standardise the tables' format on collection, than manipulating them afterwards. Good luck